# Multiple Producer and single Consumer in same ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading

**Problem statement:** Identify two consecutive integers from infinite streams of Integers, where these Integers are produced by multiple Producers but single Consumer raises an alert when same number is repeated again.

I have multiple `Producers` and single `Consumer`. If I submit Consumer to same `ExecutorService`, Consumer did not start. But if I run Consumer in separate Thread, Consumer thread starts as expected.

Code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;

public class FixedBlockingQueue {
    final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;
    private int capacity;

    public FixedBlockingQueue(int capacity){
        super();
        this.capacity = capacity;
        queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(capacity);
        System.out.println("Capactiy:"+this.capacity);
    }
    public void addElement(Integer element){
        try{
            queue.put(element);
        }catch(Exception err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void startThreads(){
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        for ( int i =0; i < 10; i++){
            es.submit(new MyProducer(this));
        }
        //es.submit(new MyConsumer(queue));
        new Thread(new MyConsumer(this)).start();
    }
    public BlockingQueue<Integer> getQueue(){
        return queue;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        FixedBlockingQueue f = new FixedBlockingQueue(1);
        f.startThreads();
    }
}

class MyProducer implements Runnable{

    private FixedBlockingQueue queue;
    public MyProducer(FixedBlockingQueue queue){
        this.queue = queue;     
    }
    public void run(){
        for ( int i=1; i< 5; i++){
            queue.addElement(new Integer(i));
            System.out.println("adding:"+i);
        }
    }
}

class MyConsumer implements Runnable{
    private BlockingQueue<Integer>  queue;
    Integer firstNumber = 0;
    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public MyConsumer(FixedBlockingQueue fQueue){
        this.queue = fQueue.getQueue();
    }
    /* TODO : Compare two consecutive integers in queue are same or not*/
    public void run(){  
        Integer secondNumber = 0;
        while ( true){
            try{
                lock.lock();
                System.out.println("queue size:"+queue.size());
                if ( queue.size() > 0) {
                    secondNumber = queue.remove();
                    System.out.println("Removed:"+secondNumber);
                    System.out.println("Numbers:Num1:Num2:"+firstNumber+":"+secondNumber);
                    if ( firstNumber.intValue() ==  secondNumber.intValue()){
                        System.out.println("Numbers matched:"+firstNumber);
                    }
                    firstNumber = secondNumber;
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(Exception err){
                err.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
Capactiy:1
adding:1
```

If I change the code from

```
es.submit(new MyConsumer(queue));
//new Thread(new MyConsumer(queue)).start();
```

to

```
//es.submit(new MyConsumer(queue));
new Thread(new MyConsumer(queue)).start();
```

Consumer thread started normally.

output:

```
Capactiy:1
adding:1
queue size:1
Removed:1
Numbers:Num1:Num2:0:1
adding:2
queue size:1
Removed:2
Numbers:Num1:Num2:1:2
adding:3
queue size:1
Removed:3
Numbers:Num1:Num2:2:3
adding:4
queue size:1
Removed:4
Numbers:Num1:Num2:3:4
adding:1
queue size:1
Removed:1
Numbers:Num1:Num2:4:1
adding:2
queue size:1
Removed:2
adding:3
Numbers:Num1:Num2:1:2
queue size:1
Removed:3
Numbers:Num1:Num2:2:3
```

In first approach :

I know that number is not consumed by Consumer but it should not block submission of other `Producer` tasks ideally.

If this is the case, use of `ExecutorService` as a replacement for simple `Threads` can't be achieved 100%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a thread pool with a single thread and a `BlockingQueue` with fixed capacity 1.  You then submit three tasks to the pool: first two that each attempt to enqueue five values each, and then one that dequeues values when any are available.

**Because your fixed-size pool has only one thread, the tasks you submit to it will run sequentially, not in parallel.**  You submit a producer task first, so it runs first.  But once it enqueues the first number, it cannot make any further progress because the queue is full.  And the queue will *remain* full forever because the producer task must finish before the pooled thread becomes available for another task, such as the consumer.

I'm not sure why you are using a thread pool for this, as it wouldn't be hard to do the thread management directly, especially since your tasks already implement `Runnable`.  If you *do* use a pool, however, then make sure it has enough threads in it to accommodate *all* the tasks concurrently.

Note also that `BlockingQueue` implementations are supposed to be thread-safe, and all those provided by the standard library indeed are so.  You therefore do not need to perform your own locking in `addElement()`.  Furthermore, if you did need to perform your own locking, then you would need to do it not just when enqueuing elements, but also when dequeuing them.

Additionally, it is surpassing strange that you have your producer task adding elements to the underlying queue indirectly, via the `FixedBlockingQueue` instance, but you have the consumer task going straight to the underlying queue.

And the name of your `FixedBlockingQueue` class is poorly chosen, because it implies that the class implements `BlockingQueue`, but the class does not in fact do so.

Comment: I have to insert the elements in arriving order and hence chose single thread with ReentrantLock. 100+ threads produce integers and I have to check two consecutive integers in order of arrival.

Comment: @Ravindrababu, what part of "`BlockingQueue`s are thread-safe" leads you to suppose that the additional locking would contribute anything that you do not get from your `BlockingQueue` automatically?

Comment: I have fixed Consumer part later, which accept same class as of Producer.

Comment: Actually I am looking for non blocking collection and will replace it shortly in my final solution.

Comment: @Ravindrababu, `LinkedList` implements `Queue`, but I fail to see why you want to avoid collections built for concurrency in a concurrent application.  In any case, do not overlook that you must synchronize / lock not only when adding elements, but also when removing them.

Comment: In my project, the number Is generated by other service where I don't have control to add checks in place. These Producer threads are really consumer of the service and I have second thoughts on BlockingQueue. These checks should happen in parallel without impacting other functionality of Producer.Your answer clarified the root cause of the problem, which I failed to grasp quickly:)

Comment: I am looking at other alternatives of using Cache with  timestamp.

Comment: +1 for suggesting that he _not_ use a thread pool.  I never could see the sense in submitting "tasks" that run forever to a thread pool.

Comment: @Ravindrababu, a `Queue` seems the natural data structure for the job as you described it.  I'm inclined to suggest a `BlockingQueue` with larger capacity than 1.  Implementation will be easier (no external synchronization needed if you do it right), and the queue capacity will accommodate the producers transiently getting ahead of the consumer.  Note that with an unbounded queue (or other unbounded data structure) your program will eventually crash if on average the consumer can't keep up with the producers, so the blocking isn't usually a negative.